# Run multiple apps in parallel?

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

Can multiple C# applications run in parallel on a raspberry pi 2 model b? [Setting a default startup app is easy](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/HelloWorld.htm), but is there any way to run more than one application simultaneously? If so, how can I switch between them in the UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 10 IoT Core does not have a shell. It runs one UWP app at a time. https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/10/hello-windows-10-iot-core/

Answer (score 5):

The answer that there is only one running Application possible - **IS WRONG**. Of course you can run multiple background applications (headless), but only one "headed" application with UI.